# $inc is not working properly in my MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do multiple queries in one statement and for some reason when I add my `$inc` statement, it does not want to work properly.

I am not getting syntax errors and when I remove the `$inc` line, it returns properly. So I am sure it is the issue. Here is my statement:

```js
db.collection("ActivityDefinition").findOneAndUpdate({
          $and: [
            {"activityDefinition.activityID": activityDefinition.activityID},
            {"activityDefinition.MAX_GROUP_ATTENDERS": { $gt: activityDefinition.totalAttendersAmount}},
            {$inc: {"activityDefinition.totalAttendersAmount": 1}}
          ]}, {
            activityDefinition
          }, {
            upsert: true,
   returnNewDocument: true
          }, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                done(err);
                return;
            }
            activities.push(activityDefinition);
            done();
            return;
        });
```

the first two lines of the `$and` work, but when I use the `$inc`, nothing is returned. I am trying to increment `totalAttendersAmount` by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the $inc operator is for the `update` clouse, and you're using in the `match` clause.

You're telling MongoDB to find a document that have a field `$inc` and, since you are allowed to have whatever you want in your document, MongoDB does't not complain of that.

If you want to increment a number, you gonna need to put the `$inc` as the seccond argument.

The method `findOneAndUpdate` has this shape of arguments:

```
findOneAndUpdate(<filter>, <update>, <options>)
```

A example based from the docs adapted for your needs would be:

```
db.collection("ActivityDefinition").findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name" : "R. Stiles" }, // filter argument
   { $inc: { "points" : 5 } } // update argument
)
```

[Here is the documentation about the `$inc` operator.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

[And here is the documentation about the `findOneAndUpdate` method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by putting `$inc` as the second argument?